# Pandas: Get list of shared values of column B that two different values from column B have in common

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table like this:

| image | user |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 |
| ... | ... |

Now I want to find shared images between two users. For example, when I ask for the images shared between `user 1` and `user 2`, I want `[1, 3]` as a result.

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on @BrendanA's answer, you can use `itertools.combinations` to get all 2-combinations, find their shared images and cast the result to a DataFrame:

```
from itertools import combinations
users_to_images = df.groupby('user')['image'].agg(set)
data = {(i,j): [list(users_to_images[i].intersection(users_to_images[j]))] for i,j in combinations(users_to_images.index, 2)}
out = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data, index=['shared_images']).T
```

Output:

```
       shared_images
(1, 2)        [1, 3]
(1, 3)        [2, 3]
(2, 3)           [3]
```

Then users 1,2 share images 1,3; users 1,3 share 2,3, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with the following

```
seen = df.groupby("user")["image"].apply(set)
shared = list(seen[1].intersection(seen[2]))

print(shared)
[1,3]
```